# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)' where every variable is non - optional

Tags: ios, swift

I get error `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'` and all the similar questions in StackOverflow says that the reason there is some optional variable but here every variable is non - nullable

```
private var j : Int!
private var inString : String!
private var outStr : String!

if self.j < self.inString.characters.count{
    var substr = self.inString.substringWithRange(
                Range<String.Index>(start: self.inString.startIndex.advancedBy(self.j), end: self.inString.endIndex))
    self.outStr.append(substr) // Here I got Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)' 
}
```

Comment: You want to just add the `String` to the variable right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is you are appending `Character`. In `String` `append` is used to append `Character`. While `substringWithRange` returns `String`. So, you have to use `appendContentsOf`.

> Method 1:

```
var j : Int!
var inString : String!
var outStr : String!

if j < inString.characters.count{
   let substr = inString.substringWithRange(inString.startIndex.advancedBy(j)..<inString.endIndex)
   outStr.appendContentsOf(substr) // Solved
}
```

> Method 2:

```
var j : Int!
var inString : String!
var outStr : String!

if j < inString.characters.count{
    let substr = inString.substringWithRange(inString.startIndex.advancedBy(j)..<inString.endIndex)
    outStr = outStr + substr
}
```

Also, `Range` is going to deprecated!